# how to get String by spliting url in android?

Tags: android

I have a google play store url "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apusapps.launcher&hl=en" from this url I have to store"com.example.launcher" in a seperate variable and compare from package name "com.example.launc" if compare I have to send a json request .how can I do that

Comment: you can use substring() method to get your desired string

Comment: use substring to get package name :)

Comment: so did you read `android.net.Uri` documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apusapps.launcher&hl=en";
String s2 =  s.substring(s.indexOf("=")+1, s.indexOf("&"));
Toast.makeText(this,"Milad: "+s2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
String urlString = url.toString();
String finalString = urlString.substring(urlString.indexOf("=")+1,urlString.lastIndexOf("&"));
if(finalString.equals(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())){
    //Your code
}
```